# Rainfall ranged series for each category in PostgresSQL

Tags: postgresql, generate-series

We have `POPULATION` and `AGE_GROUP` tables.

#### Table : `POPULATION`

Has entries as follows.

| village | age_group | male_count | female_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0-4 | 4 | 2 |
| A | 5-9 | 3 | 4 |
| A | 10-14 | 4 | 9 |
| A | 15-19 | 8 | 6 |
| A | 25-29 | 8 | 6 |

Like this we have entries for each age group (few age groups are missing, like missing `20-24`) for multiple villages called `A, B, C, D etc`.

#### Table : `AGE_GROUP`

Has entries as follows

| age_group | min_age | max_age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0-4 | 0 | 4 |
| 5-9 | 5 | 9 |
| 10-14 | 10 | 14 |
| 15-19 | 15 | 19 |
| 20-24 | 20 | 24 |
| 25-29 | 25 | 29 |
| 30-34 | 30 | 34 |
| 35-39 | 35 | 39 |
| 40-44 | 40 | 44 |
| 45-49 | 45 | 49 |
| 50-54 | 50 | 54 |
| 55-59 | 55 | 59 |
| 60-64 | 60 | 64 |
| 65-69 | 65 | 69 |
| 70-74 | 70 | 74 |
| 75-79 | 75 | 79 |
| 80-84 | 80 | 84 |
| 85-89 | 85 | 89 |
| 90-94 | 90 | 94 |
| 95-99 | 95 | 99 |
| 100 above | 100 | 150 |

No stats available for few age groups from each village. Requirements is to show `zero` for the age age groups, which are not present in that respective village in postgres query.

In case of single village, we can left join `POPULATION` table with `AGE_GROUP` table and can use `COALESCE()` function to fill the missing stats as follows.

```
SELECT
        village, 
        age_group, 
        COALESCE(male_count, 0) AS male_count, 
        COALESCE(female_count, 0) AS female_count 
FROM 
        AGE_GROUP ag
LEFT JOIN
        POPULATION p
ON 
        p.age_group = ag.age_group
```

The above query works only, if we have single village (assuming to use `COALESEC(village, 'A') as village`). But, we have multiple villages and in each village different age groups are missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first to cross join all vilages with the ag table

> ```
> CREATE TABLE POPULATION (
>   "village" VARCHAR(1),
>   "age_group" VARCHAR(5),
>   "male_count" INTEGER,
>   "female_count" INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO POPULATION
>   ("village", "age_group", "male_count", "female_count")
> VALUES
>   ('A', '0-4', '4', '2'),
>   ('A', '5-9', '3', '4'),
>   ('A', '10-14', '4', '9'),
>   ('A', '15-19', '8', '6'),
>   ('A', '25-29', '8', '6'),
>     ('B', '0-4', '4', '2'),
>   ('B', '5-9', '3', '4'),
>   ('B', '60-64', '4', '9'),
>   ('B', '15-19', '8', '6'),
>   ('B', '25-29', '8', '6');
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE AGE_GROUP (
>   "age_group" VARCHAR(9),
>   "min_age" INTEGER,
>   "max_age" INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO AGE_GROUP
>   ("age_group", "min_age", "max_age")
> VALUES
>   ('0-4', '0', '4'),
>   ('5-9', '5', '9'),
>   ('10-14', '10', '14'),
>   ('15-19', '15', '19'),
>   ('20-24', '20', '24'),
>   ('25-29', '25', '29'),
>   ('30-34', '30', '34'),
>   ('35-39', '35', '39'),
>   ('40-44', '40', '44'),
>   ('45-49', '45', '49'),
>   ('50-54', '50', '54'),
>   ('55-59', '55', '59'),
>   ('60-64', '60', '64'),
>   ('65-69', '65', '69'),
>   ('70-74', '70', '74'),
>   ('75-79', '75', '79'),
>   ('80-84', '80', '84'),
>   ('85-89', '85', '89'),
>   ('90-94', '90', '94'),
>   ('95-99', '95', '99'),
>   ('100 above', '100', '150');
> ```

> ```
> WITH CTE AS (SELECT DISTINCT "village", ag.*  FROM POPULATION CROSS JOIN AGE_GROUP ag)
> SELECT DISTINCT
>         ag.village, 
>         ag.age_group, 
>         COALESCE(male_count, 0) AS male_count, 
>         COALESCE(female_count, 0) AS female_count 
> FROM 
>         CTE ag
> LEFT  JOIN 
>         POPULATION p
> ON p."village" = ag."village" AND 
>         p.age_group = ag.age_group
> ```
>
> ```
> village | age_group | male_count | female_count
> :------ | :-------- | ---------: | -----------:
> A       | 0-4       |          4 |            2
> A       | 100 above |          0 |            0
> A       | 10-14     |          4 |            9
> A       | 15-19     |          8 |            6
> A       | 20-24     |          0 |            0
> A       | 25-29     |          8 |            6
> A       | 30-34     |          0 |            0
> A       | 35-39     |          0 |            0
> A       | 40-44     |          0 |            0
> A       | 45-49     |          0 |            0
> A       | 50-54     |          0 |            0
> A       | 55-59     |          0 |            0
> A       | 5-9       |          3 |            4
> A       | 60-64     |          0 |            0
> A       | 65-69     |          0 |            0
> A       | 70-74     |          0 |            0
> A       | 75-79     |          0 |            0
> A       | 80-84     |          0 |            0
> A       | 85-89     |          0 |            0
> A       | 90-94     |          0 |            0
> A       | 95-99     |          0 |            0
> B       | 0-4       |          4 |            2
> B       | 100 above |          0 |            0
> B       | 10-14     |          0 |            0
> B       | 15-19     |          8 |            6
> B       | 20-24     |          0 |            0
> B       | 25-29     |          8 |            6
> B       | 30-34     |          0 |            0
> B       | 35-39     |          0 |            0
> B       | 40-44     |          0 |            0
> B       | 45-49     |          0 |            0
> B       | 50-54     |          0 |            0
> B       | 55-59     |          0 |            0
> B       | 5-9       |          3 |            4
> B       | 60-64     |          4 |            9
> B       | 65-69     |          0 |            0
> B       | 70-74     |          0 |            0
> B       | 75-79     |          0 |            0
> B       | 80-84     |          0 |            0
> B       | 85-89     |          0 |            0
> B       | 90-94     |          0 |            0
> B       | 95-99     |          0 |            0
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=ff0e9d3f15ace6225d6fcf4dd5389f82)*

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. It's working perfectly.